# print the number of column2 based on column1

Tags: awk

I have a file as shown below. I would like to print the number of students in each subject(duplicated names don't want to count).

```
alvy  science
eby   maths
alvy  science
bitty science
monika maths
eby    maths 
johny  social
```

How do I get the following output with awk?

```
`no:of students in` science- 2
 no:of students in  maths -  2
 no:of students in social -  1
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that should work for you:

```
awk '!s[$1, $2]++ {arr[$2]++} 
     END {for (i in arr) print "no:of students in", i, "-", arr[i]}'
```

Comment: `(duplicated names don't want to count).` lazy solution is first do `awk '!a[$0]++'` then pipe output to your command.

Comment: @Kent: Thanks I completely overlooked that part in OP. Fixed it now.

Comment: There might be a problem if a student was doing more than one subject here, no? Perhaps `!s[$1,$2]++` would fix that...

Comment: @Scrutinizer: Valid point mate, thanks so much. I've fixed it now.